# Unicorn memory leak on Heroku when dyno is idle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks, unicorn

Short version

Memory leak and R14 errors on Heroku with Rails + Unicorn when there are no requests at all. No problem locally, or with Webrick, or when the server is under a load.

Long version

I have a Rails 4 application running on Heroku. When there is no load on the server, the memory consumption reported by Heroku goes up around 0.5 MB per minute. After a few hours, R14 errors starting to appear in the logs, and a while later the process does not respond and Heroku kills it.
I can see the increasing memory usage in New Relic as well.

`02:03:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
02:03:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 sample#memory_total=533.19MB sample#memory_rss=511.88MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=21.30MB sample#memory_pgpgin=1034783pages sample#memory_pgpgout=903740pages
02:03:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=533M(104.1%)`

Environment:
Ruby 2.1.4 + Rails 4.1.7 + Unicorn + Heroku with 1 web dyno

What I tried so far

1. Decreased the number of Unicorn workers from the default 3 to 2. Did not help, just made the memory leak a little bit slower.
2. Disabled background workers (removed from Procfile). No effect. Did not change anything.
3. Installed Unicorn Worker Killer. It did not help because there are no requests going on, so the worker killer never kicks in (is there a time based worker killer?).
4. Used ApacheBench to stress test the server. The memory usage was constant, around 190MB/process according to New Relic. There was no increase. It seems like the memory leak only happens when there is no server load.
5. Removed Unicorn and used the default Webrick. The memory usage became constant, around 208MB/instance according to New Relic!
6. Tried to reproduce this issue on local machine by starting the server in production with `RAILS_ENV=production  foreman start`. There was no memory leak in this case.

Based on point 5, I think the memory leak is related to Unicorn but somehow only happens on Heroku.
How to track down where is the problem?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be time consuming but you could try `git bisect` to narrow down the offending code that introduces the leak. If it's including Unicorn then you know that's the culprit. If not, perhaps there's something else going on in your application code (or the interesection of Unicorn + your code) that is responsible. (http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/finding-failure-git-bisect)

Comment: Additionally you may find this worth a read: http://siliconisland.ca/2013/04/26/beware-of-the-zombie-process-apocalypse/. Heroku's log-runtime-metrics may be conflicting with something in your app that forks processes (maybe Unicorn? maybe another gem?)